# Difference between time reversible and stationary distribution. "watching a movie backwards"

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, semigroups, self-adjoint-operators, stationary-processes

A time homogeneous Markov process on Ω
with semi-group $P_t$
is said to stationary w.r.t a distribution $π$
if

$$∫_{Ω}P_tf(x)dπ(x)=∫_{Ω}f(x)dπ(x), \text{for $f$ bounded measurable}.$$

and reversible if

$$∫_{\Omega}f(x)P_tg(x)dπ(x)=∫_{Ω}g(x)P_tf(x)dπ(x), \text{for $f,g$ bounded measurable.}$$

These properties are frequently be translated into words as : $\textbf{Stationary}$
once the process reaches $π$
it never leaves, $\textbf{Reversible}$
people say it is like "if you watched a movie backwards it would look the same as if you watched it forwards in time".

I completely understand the meaning of $\textbf{Stationary}$
. However I dont really understand the movie analogy, could anyone make this more concrete, i.e. could I run a simulation and observe this analogy?